# How does typescript/angular import zone.js for testing

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, zone.js

In `test.ts` of John Papa's [Angular Tour of Heroes demo project](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/src/test.ts), there are the following imports:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
```

These files aren't in the `src` directory of the app, though. They become available in `node_modules` when you `npm install` the packages defined in `package.json`. My question is: **How does Typescript/Angular know how to interpret these imports?** I mean importing modules in general, not specific to only this packge. The question merely came up as I'm setting up a testing suite.

Comment: Why these specifically, as opposed to all of the *other* imports that come from `node_modules` (like all of the `@angular` imports, or example)?

Comment: this guy named Taylor.N explained it quite well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861640/3933927)

Comment: Good point. I thought of zone.js specifically because i thought the first 'zone.js' was referring to a specific file and not a folder in `node_modules` but now I see that's mistaken, `zone.js` is just the name of the package, rather than just say `zone`. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks Stavm, that's the kind of writeup I was hoping for.